# Unity3D brings up a new VS window every time I open a script or check for an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

It does not get any deeper than this. If i double-click on a script in Unity, or double-click on an error line in the console it brings up a new Visual Studio window instead of showing the error/script in the already open solution. :/

Comment: It's annoying as hell, please help

Comment: Use monodevelop then

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the Visual Studio with Unity, I recommend you to use the unityVS, a plugin who makes integration with Visual Studio and Unity. So you can debug with Visual Studio, and more. It's free!

http://unityvs.com/

Answer (score 0):

OK, I restarted unity and it fixed it, also, I'm not sure if this mattered but I unchecked Editor > Preferences > External Tools > Editor Attaching, but I think a simple restart would make it anyways.